# Difficulty calling uploadFiles on kendo-upload component

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am having a bit of a problem uploading my selected files from my component code, the reason I've elected to go the component code route is that I need to upload those files after the overall parent aggregate object is created. This way I can assign the required IDs to my underlying requested payload in the end.

My HTML code in question looks like so:

```
<div class="wr-btn-style wr-btn-style--primary kendo-upload-container">
                                <kendo-upload 
                                #kendoUpload 
                                [saveUrl]="'resources/admin/upload-resources-documents'"
                                [restrictions]="fileRestrictions" 
                                [autoUpload]="false"
                                (uploadProgress)="uploadProgress($event)"
                                (upload)="uploadEventHandler($event)"
                                (select)="selectEventHandler($event)">
                                    <ng-template kendoUploadFileInfoTemplate let-files>
                                        <div class="width-50">
                                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
                                                <mat-label>Button Text</mat-label>
                                                <input matInput formControlName="FileBtnText" maxLength="50">
                                                <mat-hint>{{fileBtnTxt}}</mat-hint>
                                            </mat-form-field>
                                        </div>
                                    </ng-template>
                                    <kendo-upload-messages select="Select File" dropFilesHere="Drag and Drop here">
                                    </kendo-upload-messages>
                                </kendo-upload>
                            </div>
```

I do have a custom template as we have a requirement to allow the user rename their files before they upload it.

The code in question looks so:

```
    @ViewChild('kendoUpload') kendoUpload : UploadComponent;

this.resourceService.saveResource(request)
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.componentDestroyed$))
            .subscribe((x : IResourceResponseDto) => {
                if(x) {
                    this.returndResource = x;
                    this.snackBar.success("Successfully saved resource");
                    this.overallForm.markAsPristine();
                }
            }, (error) => {
                this.snackBar.error("Error saving resource");
            }, () => this.kendoUpload.uploadFiles());
```

The idea here is that after we successfully save our resource, we return a payload which includes the newly created IDs and then we can call the upload function once our subscription is successfully finished. However, I do not see any errors in the console, I do not see any calls to my endpoint from the front end either. Nor do I see it hitting my upload event handler as it is defined here:

```
uploadEventHandler(event: UploadEvent) {
        if(!this.overallForm.valid)
            return;

        let { SectionId, ResourceId } = this.returndResource;
        let data = {
            Files: event.files,
            SectionId: SectionId,
            ResourceId: ResourceId
        };

        event.data = data;
    }
```

As a sanity check I made a small [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d5tf5g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fupload.component.ts) just to verify that the uploadFiles() method actually works and does trigger an upload, it appears that it does.
Where exactly am I going awry?

Comment: Does the `.resourceService.saveResource()` observable actually complete?

Comment: @BizzyBob Yes, my breakpoints inside of the subscribe are hit, I would assume that would also trigger the complete call. The upload call wouldn't do anything either with it being part of the complete, or as part of subscribe

Answer (score 0):

I am a bloody idiot, the problem was that I was trying to upload a file that isn't part of my file restrictions. Totally forgot about that